# Как программно переключить меню в NavigationView?

Tags: java, android

```
navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);
```

данный код не работает, почему?

Потому что я проверяю в

---

```
  @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        Log.e("HomeActivity=onNavigationItemSelected", id + "");

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.nav_group:
                displayView(R.id.container,getSupportFragmentManager(), GroupFragment.class);
                break;
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

---

И onNavigationItemSelected не вызывается.

`navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this); и implements прописал`

Как программно переключить navigationView на 1 меню на R.id.nav_group?

Comment: Что разве никто не делал так чтобы при запуске открывалось по умолчанию какое - то меню автоматически, а не нажатием на пункт меню в nav drawer

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете в виду боковое меню, то при запуске используйте следующий код.

```
DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
```